# File "train.py", line 35, in clip_gradient modulenorm = p.grad.data.norm()

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am not sure why do I get this error:

```
python train.py --batch-size 20 --rnn_type GRU --cuda --gpu 1 --lr 0.0001 --mdl RNN --clip_norm 1 --opt Adam
/scratch/sjn-p2/anaconda/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
There are 2 CUDA devices
Setting torch GPU to 1
Using device:1 
Stored Environment:['term_len', 'word_index', 'glove', 'max_len', 'train', 'dev', 'test', 'index_word']
Loaded environment
Creating Model...
Setting Pretrained Embeddings
Initialized GRU model
Starting training
Namespace(aggregation='mean', attention_width=5, batch_size=20, clip_norm=1, cuda=True, dataset='Restaurants', dev=1, dropout_prob=0.5, embedding_size=300, epochs=50, eval=1, gpu=1, hidden_layer_size=300, l2_reg=0.0, learn_rate=0.0001, log=1, maxlen=0, mode='term', model_type='RNN', opt='Adam', pretrained=1, rnn_direction='uni', rnn_layers=1, rnn_size=300, rnn_type='GRU', seed=1111, term_model='mean', toy=False, trainable=1)
========================================================================
/scratch2/debate_tweets/sentiment/pytorch_sentiment_rnn/models/rnn.py:51: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  decoded = self.softmax(decoded)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 343, in <module>
    exp.train()
  File "train.py", line 326, in train
    loss = self.train_batch(i)
  File "train.py", line 303, in train_batch
    coeff = clip_gradient(self.mdl, self.args.clip_norm)
  File "train.py", line 35, in clip_gradient
    modulenorm = p.grad.data.norm()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
[jalal@goku pytorch_sentiment_rnn]$
```

for train.py file in https://github.com/vanzytay/pytorch_sentiment_rnn 
I have followed all the steps in the readme up to here.
What do you think should be fixed?

```
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
PyTorch version: 0.3.1.post2
How you installed PyTorch (conda, pip, source): conda install -c pytorch pytorch
Python version: Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 7 2017, 17:05:42)
CUDA/cuDNN version: CUDA Version 8.0.61
GPU models and configuration: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti], driver=nvidia latency=0
GCC version (if compiling from source): [GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
```

Comment: One of the model parameters has `None` grad. It is hard to tell more than this.

Comment: But I am not sure how to handle this issue? I have followed all the previous steps of the tutorial with no error

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I solved the issue (because I do not get the same accuracy as mentioned in the README section) but here's what I did:
added `if p.grad is not None:` here:

```
def clip_gradient(model, clip):
    """Computes a gradient clipping coefficient based on gradient norm."""
    totalnorm = 0
    for p in model.parameters():
        if p.grad is not None:
                modulenorm = p.grad.data.norm()
                totalnorm += modulenorm ** 2
    totalnorm = math.sqrt(totalnorm)
    return min(1, clip / (totalnorm + 1e-6))
```

and added `if p.grad is not None:` in:

```
def train_batch(self, i):
        ''' Trains a regular RNN model
        '''
        sentence, targets, actual_batch = self.make_batch(self.train_set, i)
        if(sentence is None):
            return None
        hidden = self.mdl.init_hidden(actual_batch)
        hidden = repackage_hidden(hidden)
        self.mdl.zero_grad()
        output, hidden = self.mdl(sentence, hidden)
        loss = self.criterion(output, targets)
        loss.backward()
        if(self.args.clip_norm>0):
            coeff = clip_gradient(self.mdl, self.args.clip_norm)
            for p in self.mdl.parameters():
                if p.grad is not None:
                        p.grad.mul_(coeff)
        self.optimizer.step()
        return loss.data[0]
```

The accuracies I get are as follows:
for `RNN` model:

```
python train.py --batch-size 20 --rnn_type GRU --cuda --gpu 1 --lr 0.0001 --mdl RNN --clip_norm 1 --opt Adam
[Epoch 50] Train Loss=0.953654762131 T=0.51s
Test loss=0.90144520998
Output Distribution={2: 1120}
Accuracy=0.65
```

for `TD-RNN` model:

```
python train.py --batch-size 20 --rnn_type GRU --cuda --gpu 1 --lr 0.0001 --mdl TD-RNN --clip_norm 1 --opt Adam
[Epoch 50] Train Loss=0.64427837713 T=0.99s
Test loss=0.828059911728
Output Distribution={0: 165, 1: 138, 2: 817}
Accuracy=0.719642857143
```

However the accuracy mentioned in github readme for `RNN` is:

```
[Epoch 50] Train Loss=0.680990989366
Test loss=0.810974478722
Output Distribution={0: 158, 1: 158, 2: 804}
Accuracy=0.733035714286
```

What is the possible cause for such difference is accuracy? How would you fix the issue with no drop in accuracy? Not sure if my fix is causing the drop in accuracy.

I used the fix from this link https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/model-parameters-is-none-while-training/6830/2?u=monajalal

Comment: Though your accuracy in `RNN` does not match theirs, your `TD-RNN` accuracy actually exceeds theirs. So, the part you modified is being used only by `RNN`, or by `TD-RNN` too? Also, just try and run again to see if accuracy changes.

Comment: I am actually not sure. Was going to tag you under this. I have informed him as well as PyTorch developers. The fix was told in torch community

Comment: running RNN-TD again: 
`[Epoch 50] Train Loss=0.64427837713 T=1.35s
Test loss=0.828059911728
Output Distribution={0: 165, 1: 138, 2: 817}
Accuracy=0.719642857143`

Comment: however, pretty much something off for RNN, the accuracy doesn't change at all in any of the epochs https://pastebin.com/raw/7utQhvRF